# validar formulario con imagen si el campo esta vacio?

Tags: javascript, html

Cuando el input de la imagen esta vació y le doy enviar mi javascript no se ejecuta pero cuando le adjunto un doc me dice que debo  ajuntar una imagen valida cosa que esta bien. Entonces yo necesitaría que mi if reconociera el campo vacio para mostrar ese alert. Probé con `null`, `undefined` y `" "` dentro del if, tal vez hice algo mal.

coloco solo el fragmento de codigo  de la imagen

```js
function validar(){
    
    var c =true;
    var o = document.getElementById('archivo');
    var uploadFile = o.files[0];
    if (!(/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/i).test(uploadFile.name) ) {
        alert('Ingrese un archivo con alguna de las siguientes extensiones .jpeg/.jpg/.png/.gif ');
        c= false;
    }
     return c;
    }
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validar()">
  <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo" />
  <button>Ok</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo simplemente comprobaría que se ha adjuntado algún fichero, usando tu código algo como:

```
if (o.files.length==0 || !(/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/i).test(uploadFile.name) )
```

Comment: lo probé y no ha funcionado.

Comment: Si has copiado directamente mi línea, ten encuenta que he escrito mal length

Comment: Tenes razón!, Ahora si funciona. Gracias por haberme ayudado.